# Receiving "SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table ' ' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF" When not submitting Id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using ASP.Net MVC 5 with EF6

I have a model called DoodleBug (dont ask). When I try to create and save a new entry of this entity to the database I get the following exception, even though i am not inputting an Id value?

```
SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 
'DoodleBugs' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

Here is my model

```
public class DoodleBug
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Sentence { get; set; }
    public DateTime Adate { get; set; }
    public Boolean TrueFalse { get; set; }
    public int DoodleId { get; set; }
    public int BugId { get; set; }

    public virtual Doodle Doodle { get; set; }
    public virtual Bug Bug { get; set; }


}
```

Here is the controller

```
// GET: DoodleBugs/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(db.Bug, "Id", "BugString");
        ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(db.Doodle, "Id", "DoodleString");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: DoodleBugs/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Sentence,Adate,TrueFalse,DoodleId,BugId")] DoodleBug doodleBug)        // Edited FROM [Bind(Include = "Id,Sentence,Adate,TrueFalse,DoodleId,BugId")]   ----  removed Id from bind list
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.DoodleBug.Add(doodleBug);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(db.Bug, "Id", "BugString", doodleBug.Id);
        ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(db.Doodle, "Id", "DoodleString", doodleBug.Id);
        return View(doodleBug);
    }
```

and here is the view

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>DoodleBug</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @*<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, "Id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })    
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>*@

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sentence, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sentence, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sentence, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Adate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Adate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Adate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TrueFalse, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TrueFalse)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TrueFalse, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DoodleId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DoodleId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DoodleId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BugId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BugId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BugId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

In case it helps, here is the EF generated migration code for the `DoodleBug` Entity. I manually changed some of the codelines, as noted by the comments next to them, to create a Foreign Key relationship between the `DoodleBug` entity and two other entities (`Doodle` and `Bug`)

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.DoodleBugs",
            c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),          // Edited FROM 'Id = c.Int(nullable: false)'
                Sentence = c.String(),
                Adate = c.DateTime(),
                TrueFalse = c.Boolean(),
                DoodleId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                BugId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Bugs", t => t.BugId)                      // Edited FROM 'ForeignKey("dbo.Bugs", t => t.Id)'
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Doodles", t => t.DoodleId)                // Edited FROM 'ForeignKey("dbo.Doodles", t => t.Id)'
            .Index(t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.BugId)                                       // Added
            .Index(t => t.DoodleId);                                   // Added
```

NB the controller and the view were scaffolded by EF which added both a `Bind` attribute for the ID in the `create()` method and a `SelectList` of items for the Id in the controllers ViewBag, as well as a form control in the view to utilise the `SelectList` from the controller to create a dropdown list of option to input into the Id value.

I have deleted the Id from the Bind attribute in the controllers `Create()` method and have commented out the form control in the View relating to the Id value (as seen by the @* - *@ from lines 5 - 11 in the View)

Despite this when I run the code and try to submit the form I get the above error?

When I run the app in debug mode the properties box for the `doodleBug` variable has an Id value of 0 (Int). I'm not sure where this is coming from or if it a default value?

In response to questions below are the Doodle and Bug Models

```
public class Doodle  
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DoodleString { get; set; }
    public DateTime DoodleTime { get; set; }
    public Boolean DoodleBool { get; set; }

    public virtual DoodleBug DoodleBUg { get; set; }
}

public class Bug      
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BugString { get; set; }
    public DateTime BugTime { get; set; }
    public Boolean BugBool { get; set; }

    public virtual DoodleBug DoodleBug { get; set; }
}
```

I also have some fluent API attempting to create a 1 - to - 0/1 relationship, the `DoodleBug` Entity being the optional entity to both.

```
        // 1 - 2 - 0/1
        modelBuilder.Entity<DoodleBug>()
            .HasRequired(db => db.Doodle)
            .WithOptional(d => d.DoodleBUg);

        modelBuilder.Entity<DoodleBug>()
            .HasRequired(db => db.Bug)
            .WithOptional(b => b.DoodleBug);
```

Not sure if this is what you mean by asking what my DB structure is but copied this from opening up sqlexpress;

```
dbo.DoodlBugs

Columns:
Id (PK, int, not null)
Sentence (nvarchar(max), null)
Adate (datetime, null)
TrueFalse (bit, null)
DoodleId (FK, int, not null)
BugId (FK, int, not null)

Keys
    PK_dbo.DoodleBugs
    FK_dbo.DoodleBugs_dbo.Bugs_BugId
    FK_dbo.DoodleBugs_dbo.Doodles_DoodleId
```

Comment: Can you sent your db stucture

Comment: The fact that you had to modify migration manually indicates that you have incorrect mappings, which will cause this and other issues when working with your model. Because it doesn't matter if you fixed manually your db, many EF behaviors depend of what EF *thinks* the db structure is. With that being said, do you have fluent configuration or data annotations not shown here?

Comment: Also post `Doodle` and `Bug` models. From what I see, it smells to improper attempt to setup one-to-one FK relationships.

Comment: To start with , why are you setting `ViewBag.Id` once and overwriting it immediately after that ?

Comment: @Shyju, the `Viewbag.Id` code was added by EF scaffold not me. I've left it in place for you guys to see in case it indicates to some behavior I'm not aware of but, as I said above, I commented out/deleted any reference to the controller and the View using the Id property

Comment: what is the created SQL statement? the configuration would mean the id is not transmitted, if it is in the statement this might point towards an outdated model / db schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the fact that you had to modify manually the generated migration is indication of a problem in the model.

For instance this edit

```
Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true), // Edited FROM 'Id = c.Int(nullable: false)'
```

The migration is generated based on the model. The important thing to notice here is that from EF point of view, the `Id` field is **not** identity. Although your edit fixed the database field, still for EF this field is **not** identity, hence EF does not treat it as identity and associated behaviors like not passing a value when doing `INSERT`, but like regular `int` field and passes its value (even it's 0 by default) to `INSERT` command, which leads to the exception you are getting.

Similar, the following edits

```
.ForeignKey("dbo.Bugs", t => t.BugId) // Edited FROM 'ForeignKey("dbo.Bugs", t => t.Id)'
.ForeignKey("dbo.Doodles", t => t.DoodleId) // Edited FROM 'ForeignKey("dbo.Doodles", t => t.Id)'
```

indicate that for EF `DoodleId` and `BugId` are **not** FKs (instead, `Id` is), so all the behavior and generated SQL joins will be based on that.

With that being said, never edit migrations manually to "fix" model issues, but fix the model.

The root of the problem in your case are the two one-to-one relationships. By default, EF uses so called [Shared Primary Key Associations](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations) for such relationships, where the PK of the dependent table is also a FK to the principal table. And of course the PK of the dependent table is no more identity.

How to fix it? The problem is that one-to-one FK associations have limited support. More specifically, explicit FK properties are not supported. So you have to remove them from the model and keep only the navigation properties:

```
public class DoodleBug
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Sentence { get; set; }
    public DateTime Adate { get; set; }
    public Boolean TrueFalse { get; set; }
    public virtual Doodle Doodle { get; set; }
    public virtual Bug Bug { get; set; }
}
```

and change the configuration as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DoodleBug>()
    .HasRequired(db => db.Doodle)
    .WithOptional(d => d.DoodleBUg)
    .Map(c => c.MapKey("DoodleId"));

modelBuilder.Entity<DoodleBug>()
    .HasRequired(db => db.Bug)
    .WithOptional(b => b.DoodleBug)
    .Map(c => c.MapKey("BugId"));
```

Now the generated migration (w/o edits!) is:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.DoodleBug",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Sentence = c.String(),
            Adate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
            TrueFalse = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
            BugId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            DoodleId = c.Int(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Bug", t => t.BugId)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Doodle", t => t.DoodleId)
    .Index(t => t.BugId)
    .Index(t => t.DoodleId);
```

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to do this in the comments but have to say thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: You are welcome mate, glad it helped :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving this error. In my case I changed the column on database (setting Identity) after I created with scaffolding the context in the MVC app. So I needed to remove this line from the DataContext class

```
 entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
```

And this solve my problem! Good luck!